# How to efficiently determine whether there is a record in millions of records?

Tags: database, hashmap, nosql

I want to check whether there is a record in millions of records.

I know I can store the records in some relational database with an index.

But I want some other resolutions, more efficiently.

I need an IDEA.

redis? mongodb? leveldb? cluster?

Comment: A million is not much^^ a hashmap requires the programm to stay up, a DB os a good way, why not the DB ? What means "more efficiently" ?

Comment: I agree with @azro 1M is not a lot. Tho, you can look into leveldb, lmdb etc...